# How to select fragments of an existing SVG using Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to run [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) locally, but the Snap.load() function makes an AJAX request, which isn't allowed locally (in Chrome, anyways). Below is my code:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var s = Snap("#headDiv");
    Snap.load("emotions.svg", function(f) {

        eyes = f.select("#eyes");
        lids = f.select("#lids");
        head = f.select("#head");

        s.append(f);
    });
};
```

So while this works fine from a server, I'd like to get this to run locally. What would be my best option to include my **emotions.svg** file without making an AJAX request?

I know it's easy to just throw the SVG in the DIV, but I wasn't able to access the fragments that way with my current script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Changing:

```
window.onload = function () {

var s = Snap("#headDiv");
Snap.load("emotions.svg", function(f) {

    eyes = f.select("#eyes");
    lids = f.select("#lids");
    head = f.select("#head");

    s.append(f);
});
};
```

To simply:

```
window.onload = function () {

    eyes = Snap.select("#eyes");
    lids = Snap.select("#lids");
    head = Snap.select("#head");
};
```

And then placing the actual SVG script in the target DIV worked great.

Comment: how does that work? where is Snap looking for those elements (#eyes, etc)?